# How to get the output of cat as a string instead of printing it?

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to get the output of the `cat()` command as a string (instead of having it printed to the screen).  I thought that `paste()` would do this, but there are differences:

```
> cat("A", c(1,2,3), sep=",")
A,1,2,3
> paste("A", c(1,2,3), sep=",")
[1] "A,1" "A,2" "A,3"
> paste("A", c(1,2,3), collapse=",")
[1] "A 1,A 2,A 3"
```

Is there a function to get what `cat()` would print?

Comment: You can use `capture.output`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also adapt your current code:

```
paste(c("A", c(1,2,3)), collapse = ",")
      ↑↑             ↑
[1] "A,1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 3):

If we specifically want to do this with `cat` (`How to get the output of cat as a string instead of printing it?`), then capture the output with `capture.output`.  The `print/cat` returns `NULL`

```
capture.output(cat("A", c(1,2,3), sep=","))
#[1] "A,1,2,3"
```

If we want to get the output written, it has the option `file`

```
cat("A", c(1, 2, 3), sep=",",  file = "file.txt")
```

---

Or using `toString` from `base R`

```
toString(c("A", c(1,2,3)))
#[1] "A, 1, 2, 3"
```

---

Or with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)
str_c(c("A", c(1,2,3)), collapse=",")
#[1] "A,1,2,3"
```

Comment: Sadly, `toString()` has extra spaces.

Comment: @jochen  you can use `gsub(" ", "", toString(c("A", c(1,2,3))))`